# Display mysql join/union results differently based on table

Tags: php, mysql, join, union

I need to generate a list of activity from multiple tables in order of the date they were entered into the tables, but when I spit them out (with php), I want each result to look specific to a design that I have for each table.

I.e... I have the tables: `listings`, `photos`, `comments`

- The results from listings should be designed a certain way, the results from photos should be designed a different way, the results from comments should be designed a third way.
- I would like to mesh the results from all three tables into one date-ordered list.

I can pull the results with a MySQL join, but I don't know how to alter the results according to the table.

Does this make a sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process is this:

- Query Database, get results back ordered by date
- Iterate over results creating table, based on date/variable you will assign a CSS class to the current row you are creating. (use an if/switch/function etc. to figure out what class should be assigned)
- After iteration is done complete the table / etc. and display.

Comment: (use an if/switch/function etc. to figure out what class should be assigned)...

i guess what i am missing is how do i tell which table the result came from? i can get the results from the column, but i dont know how to identify which table it was in...

Comment: When you query you can do something like this for a naming convention:

SELECT myTable1.value1 as value1, myTable2.value2 as value2 FROM myTable1 LEFT JOIN myTable2 ON (myTable1.id=myTable2.id) ORDER BY myTable1.date; When you get your results you will have value1 and value2 instead of column names.

Comment: Those results assume that you are going to use mysql_fetch_assoc or mysql_fetch_array for your results and not mysql_fetch_rows.  You will need an associative array that you can read the key from to tell what result column you are working with.